# setTimeout is not working when app is closed

Tags: javascript, cordova, settimeout

Working on Ionic and [local notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/) I am going to show an alert\notification to user after 10 mins of the opening of the app. which is displaying fine using this code:

```
            setTimeout(function(){
                addLocalNotification({
                    id:        "10",
                    date:       new Date(), 
                    message:    "You are welcome",  
                    title:      "Hi",
                });
            },600000)
```

*i don't want to set date in function here above (date: new Date(), ).
I want to use it with* **setTimeout**
but the problem is if user open the app and closed it then setTimeout do not work.

How can i enforce setTimeout to work even if the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The app goes to sleep when user puts your application on background. You would need something like [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) plugin for your application and then call

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // cordova.plugins.backgroundMode is now available
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
}, false);
```

This does the following

> To prevent the app from being paused while in background, the backroundMode.enable interface has to be called.

Comment: closed app means it is in background?

Comment: I assume you use Android. It is background if you can see it on the recent apps list. So yes, practically when you press home button, it will put it on background and to sleep. That plugin prevents it and thus the code can be executed even though the app isn't shown on screen.

Comment: i will also make different platform for it. will this work on cross platform?

Comment: As told on the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#supported-platforms), the supported platforms are iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Then you most probably didn't use it correctly, it is really hard to tell exactly how to do every single little thing correctly.

Comment: i simply use it as u describe

Comment: it were implemented successfully i also saw its specific notification

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: Sorry, what??

Comment: i implemented the plugin it also shows it own notification as well that havey calculation in background ...etc

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: If you took a while to read the documentation, you would've noticed that to disable that notification, you can call `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
    silent: true
})`

Comment: thank you Sanfor most of your answer help me but the main problem still persist. if i close the app then setTimeout not working. sorry

Comment: On what platform you are testing? Also how do you close the app?

Comment: android, closing app i drag it to out of the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68650/discussion-between-sanfor-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).